# How do I link to OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, opengl

I have installed VS 2008, and I have copied these libraries:

- opengl32.lib
- glu32.lib
- glut32.lib

into the library folder, and the corresponding header files into the include folder.

I have also added these files in project properties->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies:

- Opengl32.lib
- glu32.lib
- glut32.lib

Do i have to use quotes to add them?  Like this: `"Opengl32.lib" "glu32.lib" "glut32.lib"`

I created the following program, which just displays a window:

```
#include<GL/glut.h>

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFlush();
}

void main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("3D gasket");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

But linking fails with the following output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: vs, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glFlush referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glLoadIdentity referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glClear referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutMainLoop referenced in function _main
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glClearColor referenced in function _main
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutDisplayFunc referenced in function _main
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutCreateWindow referenced in function _main
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutInitWindowSize referenced in function _main
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutInitDisplayMode referenced in function _main
1>pr1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glutInit referenced in function _main
1>D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\projects\vs\Debug\vs.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\projects\vs\vs\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>vs - 11 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

I don't know what is causing these problems, can anyone explain these messages in detail?  And how to resolve them?

Comment: Instead of enclosing each line in back-quotes, you normally want to use the 'code' button (pair of curly braces) to mark a section as code (or just add four spaces of indentation + a blank line before and after).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following NeHe Tutorial:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/

Make sure you have `windows.h` included prior to any OpenGL header, and also include `gl\GL.h`. The tutorial is a bit outdated with the use of `glaux` but is still solid for first time users, and later articles remove the `glaux` dependency.

Or alternatively this Lighthouse 3D lesson:

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/setup-basics/